# Javascript toggle/switch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, switch-statement

Is there a better way to achieve a toggle/switch then what I use. It works but it just seems clumsy to me.

```
var foo = true;

$(document).on("click","$element",function(){
    if(foo){
     //code
     foo = false;
    }
    else{
      //code
      foo = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: It depends on whether the code *only* flips foo, or whether anything else happens within the code blocks..

Comment: Nope, that seems okay to me. If you're just trying to reverse the values HBP's answer below will do that, if you need more code in there, as indicated by the //code comments, then it seems you're doing it right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is shorter and sweeter :

```
   foo = !foo
```

Unless the intermediate code is different in which case the solution depends on that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var foo = true;
$(document).on("click","$element",function(){ foo=!foo; }
```

however because you're using jQuery, you may want to store it in the data attributes:

```
$(document).on("click","$element",function(){
  $(this).data('foo', !$(this).data('foo'));
});
```